# Voting on question disabled because voting on answers?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

I voted on the answer, not on the question. or does starring count as voting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that means you voted and then un-voted. So you voted up or down and then cancelled the vote.

Comment: maybe my mind plays tricks on me but i only upvoted. maybe the 2nd time i visited that page the upvote was not visible, so i clicked a 2nd time.

i tried it on another post again, as soon as i unvote, the error message appears, but then my original vote disappears as well.

Comment: reloading brings back the original vote.

Comment: @akira - did you use the browser's "back" button to return to the page? If so, unless you've reloaded the page via f5 it doesn't show the results of the AJAX.

Comment: @ChrisF: no, i clicked the already marked upvote button, the message box appeared, i dismissed the message box, the upvote button get unmarked. when i now relead the question the upvote button is marked again.